# Trying To Send commands to Bukkit server using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, if-statement, bukkit

I am new to programming in Java and would like to send messages from a client to a server using If Statements.

So I'm developing a Bukkit Plugin that will be used on a server WITHOUT BungeeCord. What I would like to do is when someone sends a command (ex:On server 1) that my plugin recognizes, I would like it to execute on that server and send the command to another server for it to execute it.

```
if (cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("OTWG"))
{
  if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("kick"))
  {
    if (sender instanceof Player)
    { // prevents possible NPE
      if (sender.hasPermission("net.OTWG.kick"))
      {
        if (args.length == 1)
        {
          sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[OTWG] " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Please enter a players name!");
          return true;
        }
        else if (args.length >= 2)
        { // Corrected from: args.length > 1
          Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayerExact(args[1]);
          if (target != null)
          { // prevents possible NPE
            target.kickPlayer(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[OTWG] " + ChatColor.GRAY + "You were kicked by " + sender.getName());
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[OTWG]" + ChatColor.GRAY + "The player " + target.getName() + " was kicked by " + sender.getName());
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[OTWG] " + ChatColor.GRAY + "You do not have the permissions to do this action.");
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (sender.hasPermission("net.OTWG.kick"))
      {
        if (args.length == 1)
        {
          sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[OTWG] " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Please enter a players name!");
          return true;
        }
        else if (args.length >= 2)
        { // Corrected from: args.length > 1
          Player target = Bukkit.getServer().getPlayerExact(args[1]);
          if (target != null)
          { // prevents possible NPE
            target.kickPlayer(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[OTWG] " + ChatColor.GRAY + "You were kicked by " + sender.getName());
            Bukkit.getServer().broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[OTWG]" + ChatColor.GRAY + "The player " + target.getName() + " was kicked by " + sender.getName());
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      else
      {
        sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[OTWG] " + ChatColor.GRAY + "You do not have the permissions to do this action.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So when, for example, someone sends the kick command, and the person is on the other server, it will  send the command o the other server and the server will then execute it.

Now for my problem.

I'm having a bit of trouble getting it so that when I say (Ex: /OTWG kick {Player}), it sends it to the other server for it to execute it.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: `would like to send messages from a client to a server using If Statements` what? I am not sure what you mean. Can you provide more information like some pseudocode?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

Comment: You can do everything with just ifs and gotos, but usually it's much easier to use for, while and other constructs too!

Comment: @isnot2bad - Actually, in this case, method calls are even more important.

Comment: @Pshemo  I Added more information, sorry for not being clear the first time.

Comment: If I ware you I would probably delete this question since it lost its impact (it is not at top of question queue). Consider creating same question after you delete it tomorrow, or maybe even better after weekend when more people are at SO.

Comment: This would probably do better on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible outside of using BungeeCord, other than writing to a website, and having the other server read from that site, however I am not a web programmer, so I wouldn't know how to do that. Sorry for not being very descriptive.